# Generate new log file everyday for long running apps in Android

Tags: android, logging, log4j

I am currently using the following code for configuring log file in Android and storing it in external path.

```
public static Logger getLogger(Class clazz) {
    final LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
    String logsFolderName;
    logsFolderName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "player/logs/";
    String logFileName = "player." + getCurrentDateString() + ".log";
    logConfigurator.setFileName(logsFolderName + logFileName);
    logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.INFO);
    logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.INFO);
    logConfigurator.setUseFileAppender(true);
    logConfigurator.setFilePattern("%d %-5p [%c{2}]-[%L] %m%n");
    logConfigurator.setMaxFileSize(1024 * 1024 * 5);
    logConfigurator.setImmediateFlush(true);
    logConfigurator.configure();
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(clazz);
    return log;
}
```

Whenever the application starts, logs are appended into current date's file. But if app is long running, how do I dynamically change the log file name on day end ?
How do I configure the `RollingFileAppender` for the same ?

Comment: Why not simply named the file with the date or categorise them into different date folder

Comment: AlarmManger can broadcast at the time of EOD. You can receive event, generate Log and save with current date (ddMMYYYYtimestamp)  or you can simply read your existing log file and append current day log. You can use timestamp as heading.